# DOM traversal one by one node using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I wanted to traverse node by node on a web page by maintaining sequence.

e.g. Below is basic DOM :

```
<BODY>
     <DIV id ='1'> Test 1 </DIV>
     <DIV id='2'> Details about <SPAN id='3'> Execution </SPAN> </DIV>   
</BODY>
```

As per above example I want traverse each node by node i.e.

```
1st Traversal : <BODY>

2nd Traversal : <DIV id ='1'>

3rd Traversal : <DIV id='2'>

4rd Traversal : <SPAN id='3'>
```

My motive is to loop over all the nodes available on current page and visit each node one by one saying simply nextnode(), while traversing not looking in to parent and child relations. Exepcted is, it should visit each node by following sequence.

So my statement will be like this :

```
startnode //consider this is start node

While ( startnode!=null ) {

  // will process on startnode

   startnode= startnode->nextnode();
  // something like that to visit each node
}
```

Is any one knows about this, how to achieve this using jquery(preferably) or javascript,
please share their references.

Thanks

-Pravin

Comment: @pravin Are you looking for `$('*')` ?

Comment: @Avinash : M sorry, can you bit explore this....do u mean to say is all nodes on page...

Comment: In `$('*')`, `" * "` selector is used to select Every **node** on your page.

Comment: I think it wont select text Node...like in above example innerHTML of <div id='1'> i.e. Test 1. Here it will jump prper nodes like <body>,<div>,<div>,<span>. How do i achieve if i want : <body> , <div>, Test 1, <div>,Details about, <SPAN>, Execution     is this possible ?

Comment: @pravin - You can get the content of those nodes while you're iterating over them, but your example does *not* have the text node, you should update the question for exactly what you're after.

Comment: @Nick : yeah that's right i ll get text node while iterating...and sure...will update my question..Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's always the standard Crockford *walk the dom* method.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FJeaY/

```
var walk_the_DOM = function walk(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walk(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};

walk_the_DOM(document.body, function(node) {
    if(node.nodeType == 1)
        alert(node.id);  // alert if we have a type 1 node
})​;​
```

*Specific `walk_the_DOM` code example copied from here:* http://snipplr.com/view/19815/walking-the-dom/

**EDIT:** Text nodes have `nodeType = 3`, so you can add that to your `if()` statement if those are desired as well.

```
walk_the_DOM(document.body, function(node) {
    if(node.nodeType == 1 || node.nodeType == 3)
        alert(node.id);  // ID will be undefined if it is a text node
})​;​
```

Comment: great recursive code for traverse parent to child in DOM tree

Answer (score 12):

You can loop through with a body and [all selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/), like this:

```
$("body").find("*").andSelf().each(function() {
    alert(this.nodeName); //alerts body, div, div, span
});​
```

**Note**: `andSelf` has been deprecated and is now an alias for `addBack()`, which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gmbj8/1/), the `body` portion is so you don't get the `<head>` and it's contents, etc.

Comment: This has two down-votes. I'm curious as well since the answer is correct. Down-voters should be decent and explain why.

Comment: exactly...this answer seems good ...please add comment who down-votes, so i also come to know is there any other reason to mark like that....

Comment: This doesn't include `<body>`.

Comment: @Roatin - Why didn't you say so? Updated.

Comment: Well, +1 if for no other reason than the fact that you nearly *always* give constructive comments in lieu of a down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

```
function walk(node, fn) {
    if (node) do {
        fn(node);
        if (node.nodeType === 1) walk(node.firstChild, fn);
    } while (node = node.nextSibling);
}
```

Usage:

```
walk(document.body, function(){
    // do something with `this`
    // e.g.
    alert(this.id);
});
```

And to avoid non-element nodes, this will work:

```
function walk(node, fn) {
    if (node) do {
        if (node.nodeType === 1) {
            fn(node);
            walk(node.firstChild, fn);
        }
    } while (node = node.nextSibling);
}
```